# PHP: How to delete user without delete the 'authenticate' function

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, rest, slim

Today I create a function in my web service to delete user from table in mysql.
I use SLIM framework to build my RESTful API.

this is the function in my class user:

```
    public function deleteUser($user_id) 
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE 
                                      FROM users
                                      WHERE user_id = ?");
        if($stmt == FALSE)
        {
            die($this->conn->error);
        }
        else 
        {
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $num_affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
            $stmt->close();
            return $num_affected_rows > 0;
        }
    }
```

and this is my code in index.php

```
    $app->delete('/users/:user_id', 'authenticate', function() use($app) 
    {
        global $user_id;

        $db = new User();
        $response = array();

        $result = $db->deleteUser($user_id);

        if ($result) 
        {
            // user deleted successfully
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "User deleted succesfully";
        } 
        else 
        {
            // user failed to delete
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "User failed to delete. Please try again!";
        }
        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    });
```

the problem is my authenticate function is get the user_id from user table for placed in header authorization.

```
  function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) 
  {
     // Getting request headers
     $headers = apache_request_headers();
     $response = array();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
     $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

     // Verifying Authorization Header
      if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) 
      {
         $db = new User();

         // get the api key
         $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
         // validating api key
         if (!$db->isValidApiKey($api_key)) 
         {
             // api key is not present in users table
             $response["error"] = true;
             $response["message"] = "Access Denied. Invalid Api key";
             echoRespnse(401, $response);
             $app->stop();
         } 
         else 
         {
             global $user_id;
             // get user primary key id
             $user_id = $db->getUserId($api_key);
         }
      } 
      else 
      {
         // api key is missing in header
         $response["error"] = true;
         $response["message"] = "Api key is misssing";
         echoRespnse(400, $response);
         $app->stop();
      }
  }
```

so everytime  I tried to delete the user with 'user_id', it always goes wrong because the system will be delete users depends on API KEY which is submited in header authorization.

My Goal is : the delete function will be deleting the user with ther user id.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quite fishy in these lines of code:

```
else 
{
    global $user_id;
    // get user primary key id
    $user_id = $db->getUserId($api_key);
}
```

The big question for yourself is, what is the scope of the $user_id as the global variable?

Authenticate function will run before you executing the `deleteUser($user_id)`, so no matter how hard you try, you will end up deleting the current authenticated user because `$user_id = $db->getUserId($api_key)` will store the current authenticated user_id to the global variable.

This will be very bad for your implementation because cureent user gonna delete itself. That's not cool man. So I suggest you the easiest workaround such as:

1. First declare another variable beside `global $user_id` named `global $executor_id`
2. Then, change your code from `$user_id = $db->getUserId($api_key);` to `$executor_id = $db->getUserId($api_key);` It assigns who will execute the delete function.
3. Then make your delete() function in index.php like this:

   ```
   $app->delete('/users/:user_id', 'authenticate', function() use($app) 
   {
       global $user_id;
       global $executor_id;

       $db = new User();
       $response = array();

       $user_id = // please get the user_id that would be deleted here.

       $result = false;
       if($user_id != $executor_id)
           $result = $db->deleteUser($user_id);

       if ($result) 
       {
           // user deleted successfully
           $response["error"] = false;
           $response["message"] = "User deleted succesfully";
       } 
       else 
       {
           // user failed to delete
           $response["error"] = true;
           $response["message"] = "User failed to delete. Please try again!";
       }
       echoRespnse(200, $response);
   });
   ```

Sorry, I am not familiar with SLIM Framework, but Hope it helps :)

Comment: I would add to this answer that you REALLY should get out of the habit of using `global` declarations in favor of dependency injection. That will help you avoid scope problems such as this altogether.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you @MikeBrant :D